# p:dialogue displayed only after 2 clicks on the p:commandButton

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to delete one row of the [p:dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7jNv.png).

- For the first click on *Delete button*, the dialog cannot displayed.
- For the second click on *Delete button*, the dialog is displayed and so the action is done with success.

**The Bean is:**

```js
@Component()
@Scope("request")
public class ListTrainings 
{
 @Autowired
 public ListTrainings(@Qualifier("applicationManager") ApplicationManager appMgr)
 {
    this.appMgr= appMgr;
    lfs  =  new  ArrayList<Formation>();
    tm  =  new TrainingModel();
    formation = new  Formation();
 }
  
 @PostConstruct
 public void Initialize()
 {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
 }

 public  void  selectedRow()
 {
    status1 =  false;
    status2 =  false;
    tm  =  (TrainingModel)  listDatas.getRowData();
    formation =  appMgr.listTrainingsByRef(tm.getId()).get(0);
    vb.setFormation(formation);  
    if(
                  (appMgr.listTrainersByRefTraining(formation.getFormationId()).size()  == 0)
                  &&
                  (formation.getSalleEspace() == null)
             )
      { status1 =  true; }
      else
      { status2 =  true; }
 }
}
```

**The Button on XHTML is:**

```html
<p:commandButton id="btn"
       value="3" 
       oncomplete="if(#{listTrainings.status1}) {PF('dlg1').show();}
                   if(#{listTrainings.status2}) {PF('dlg3').show();}"
       update="aw">
       <f:ajax render="btn" execute="@all" listener="#{listTrainings.selectedRow}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
```

When button action click use with widget name by p:dialog.This button of onclick method call by widget name.Add dialog like below code.

```
<p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
<h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
```

Comment: hello @hsntpn, thanks a lot for your reply but I'd like to use condition (if ... if ..) on onclick like I mentioned on my question.